# Python: Unmatched group exception

Tags: regex, replace, python-2.7

I have the string consisting times and I wanted to format the times to 12hrs format.

I tried,

```
pat1 = "(\d+):(\d+)?\s*pm"
pat1 = "(\d+):(\d+)?\s*am"
hooString = "673 HOO: Mon. 7:30 am - 6pm, Tue. 7:30am - 6 pm, Wed. 7:30 am - 6 pm, Thurs. 7:30 am - 6 pm, Fri. 8 am - 5 pm,"
hooString  = sub(compile(pat1, IGNORECASE), "\1:\2 AM", hooString)
hooString  = sub(compile(pat2, IGNORECASE), "\1:\2 PM", hooString)
print hooString
```

I got the output as,

```
673 HOO: Mon. 7:30 AM - 6pm, Tue. 7:30 AM - 6 pm, Wed. 7:30 AM - 6 pm, Thurs. 7:30 AM - 6 pm, Fri. 8 am - 5 pm,
```

But I required "8am or 8 am" also to be replaced to "8 AM", so I slightly changed regex to

```
pat1 = "(\d+):?(\d+)?\s*am"
pat2 = "(\d+):?(\d+)?\s*pm"
```

It throws me "unmatched group" exception. because of the 2nd group doesn't exists in input string.

How could I get my expected result without exception for both the conditions "%H:%M %P" as well as "%H %p"

Also If I could get the result for "8 am" as "8:00 AM" that could be the best answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why have two groups in the first place?

```
pat1 = r"(\d+(?:[:]\d+)?)\s*am"
pat1 = r"(\d+(?:[:]\d+)?)\s*pm"
```

Note the use of a raw string. Otherwise you might get problems with escaping.

What did I do? I just stuff the whole time into one group, and made `:\d+` optional (with a non-capturing group). Replacement would of course be `\1 AM` and `\1 PM`.

Comment: thanks worked great. Any posibility to make 5 AM to 5:00 AM. ie, if its rounded hour I want minutes as 00.

Comment: @flower maybe with a second pass. you can't conditionally make magic characters appear in a replacement string only. (or you would have to use `re.sub` with a replacement callback)

Comment: Thanks I 'll apply replacement callback.

Comment: @flower note that you can then simplify it to one regex: `r"(\d+(?:[:]\d+)?)\s*([ap]m)` and convert group `2` to uppercase automatically

Comment: in some cases a.m, p.m, a.m., p.m. arrives instead of AM and PM.

Comment: @flower so use `r"(\d+(?:[:]\d+)?)\s*([ap][.]?m)` I guess? You can do all the sanitization in the callback